Can you pray for others while in a state of mortal sin?
I know there are some kinds of prayer that you cannot do while in a state of mortal sin, but then I read somewhere that you can pray for your own salvation, but can you pray for the salvation of another person?

I do not think we should pray for one another as everyone has their special relationship with God , this is why Jesus compared the tax collector to the Pharisee, neither was praying for the other because each one of them had their special relationship with God

"Can you" or "should you"?

@Geremia Obviously God knows what you are saying but I was under the impression that in general He won't answer your prayers in a state of mortal sin

@SoFewAgainstSoMany no, Christ compared the tax collector to the Pharisee because the one was humble and the other was exalting himself.

@eques, we shouldn't pray for each other, that's why you were given a mouth to speak for yourself.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany That's a claim you make. It's obvious that not everyone agrees with you. the Bible doesn't agree with you "pray one for another, that you may be saved" James 5:16. Further this question is tagged Catholicism, so your personal theological opinions are off-topic.

@eques, didn't know about that verse , my friend from a different denomination taught me that but apparently she is wrong

I'm not sure if there is any official teaching on this with respect to prayer, but we can perhaps draw an analogy with the Church's teaching on the reception of sacramental graces. In short, if you receive a sacrament validly while in a state of mortal sin, the sacrament really takes effect, but you will not receive any of the habitual graces associated with it. Dr. Taylor Marshall explains it well

A 14 year old boy could validly receive the sacrament of Confirmation in a state of mortal sin. He would receive zero habitual grace upon reception of the sacrament because of the obstruction of mortal sin. However, if he were not making an explicit act of the will against receiving the sacrament of Confirmation, he would validly receive the sacrament (and the indelible character of Confirmation), but not the grace of the sacrament, nor the indwelling of the Holy Spirit.
If he stayed away from Christ and the Church for 30 years from that day but then one day he made a good confession, suddenly at that moment of absolution, his soul would be FLOODED not just with the grace of justification, but with all the graces of Confirmation that had been held in reserve until that moment. This is why people sometimes experience such a spiritual experience when they make a confession after a long time. They are receiving sacramental graces accrued from the past!

I would imagine that any graces that come from any prayers you prayed in a state of mortal sin would be delayed until you made a good confession. You are right that there are certain kinds of prayer that just aren't effective if you pray them in the state of mortal sin, most notably prayers for indulgences. Manuals on indulgences will tell you that one of the general requirements is that the worker does the indulged work in a state of grace. So your indulgences for the souls in purgatory at least would not be effective if you tried to obtain them in a state of grace.
That all being said, whether or not your prayers for others are effective while in a state of mortal sin should not concern you, as you should be seeking forgiveness for mortal sin at the earliest possible time, and not merely the earliest convenient time. Concern for your own soul should overrule concern for anything else while you are in mortal sin.

If a person in mortal sin says some prayers in order to obtain an indulgence, he wouldn't get the indulgence, but the prayer, if sincere, could still have an effect.

@AndreasBlass that is true, and I didn't mean to imply the prayers for an indulgence could not have any effect whatsoever.

This answer is entirely based on catholic interpretation and ignores my own beliefs.
The answer is a "qualified" yes.

So our merciful God is always there to begin the process of reconciliation, including acting as the Good Shepherd to bring back a wandering sheep to the fold (see Matt. 18:12-13). This could include the sincere prayer of one in mortal sin regarding a loved one. God can use that prayer to foster the sinner’s own reconciliation. (Catholic.com Praying while in mortal sin)


As previously stated, this was a recommendation and not a commandment. It was also related to a very specific set of circumstances in the early Christian community. We can still pray for those who are in mortal sin today. (Catholic.com Can we pray for those in mortal sin)


But does it help the other person?

@wmasse From my understanding yes. How God will respond to a prayer however is something no one is able to answer. God hears the prayer. See Luke 11:8-11. The majority of prayers affect us internally, but God is always listening. We might just not be properly listening for God's answer.

I don't know.  It's phrased in a very odd way there and I don't want to read anything into it.  What then would be the thing about not being able to pray in a state of mortal sin then?

@wmasse If you had a source for that, I would be able to properly address it. All I could do with your original answer was respond with a general answer from catholic sources. Which does not seem to align with your "you cannot pray" claim.

The notion that God doesn't listen to prayers when you're in a state of sin comes from Isaiah 59:1-2.

Behold, the LORD’S hand is not shortened, that it cannot save; neither
his ear heavy, that it cannot hear: But your iniquities have separated
between you and your God, and your sins have hid his face from you,
that he will not hear.

But the typical interpretation of this passage is grossly out of its natural context. It's not talking about a person who has backslidden or done something they shouldn't have. It's talking about Israel in general, who had completely rebelled against God, his covenant, and his law. They had gone into a state of complete degradation, murder, injustice, etc.
This is the rest of the passage, which explains why they're separated from God, why he hid his face from them, and why he will not hear them:

For your hands are defiled with blood, and your fingers with iniquity;
your lips have spoken lies, your tongue hath muttered perverseness.
None calleth for justice, nor any pleadeth for truth: they trust in
vanity, and speak lies; they conceive mischief, and bring forth
iniquity. They hatch cockatrice’ eggs, and weave the spider’s web: he
that eateth of their eggs dieth, and that which is crushed breaketh
out into a viper. Their webs shall not become garments, neither shall
they cover themselves with their works: their works are works of
iniquity, and the act of violence is in their hands. Their feet run to
evil, and they make haste to shed innocent blood: their thoughts are
thoughts of iniquity; wasting and destruction are in their paths. The
way of peace they know not; and there is no judgment in their goings:
they have made them crooked paths: whosoever goeth therein shall not
know peace.
Therefore is judgment far from us, neither doth justice overtake us:
we wait for light, but behold obscurity; for brightness, but we walk
in darkness. We grope for the wall like the blind, and we grope as if
we had no eyes: we stumble at noonday as in the night; we are in
desolate places as dead men. We roar all like bears, and mourn sore
like doves: we look for judgment, but there is none; for salvation,
but it is far off from us. For our transgressions are multiplied
before thee, and our sins testify against us: for our transgressions
are with us; and as for our iniquities, we know them; In transgressing
and lying against the LORD, and departing away from our God, speaking
oppression and revolt, conceiving and uttering from the heart words of
falsehood. And judgment is turned away backward, and justice standeth
afar off: for truth is fallen in the street, and equity cannot enter.
Yea, truth faileth; and he that departeth from evil maketh himself a
prey: and the LORD saw it, and it displeased him that there was no
judgment.

God hears your prayers, even when you are imperfect. And we should pray for others. Paul repeatedly asks for prayers, or recounts the prayers made for his readers (2 Cor. 1:11, 9:14; Col. 1:9; 1 Thes. 5:25; 2 Thes. 3:1; Heb. 13:18).

The question is tagged Catholicism.

@wmasse  Are you suggesting that this answer conflicts with Catholicism? I don't see a conflict.

I would draw an analogy with physical illness: If you are having terminal disease, you still can help others to a limited extend given by the illness.
Mortal sin is understood as a spiritual terminal illness. It can be separated from other deeds of the person.

Can you please provide supporting evidence from a Catholic source to back up your answer.

It is a metaphor to facilitate understanding catholic point of view. If you have any project then there are always deeds that can destroy the project completely (mortal sins) and deeds which are not so dangerous (venial sins). The one of the main projects in Catholicism is an eternal life and avoidance of eternal damnation. But a person has many goals and many projects. So you can still be active in these other projects despite the fact that your main project is in shatters.  Judas Iscariot was in mortal sin when buying a field of a potter - so some deeds of mortal sinner can be good.
